# bash does not get root permissions with setuid program

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

I have the following home-grown implementation of `su`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf ("Usage: %s command [argument]...\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (geteuid () != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s: permissions are wrong or the setuid bit is not set.\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    argv++;

    int ret = execv (argv[0], argv);

    if (ret == -1) {
        perror (argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

To allow for proper execution, the permissions and ownership information are set accordingly:

```
$ gcc su.c -o su
$ sudo chown root: su
$ sudo chmod 4755 su
```

When I invoke a shell, such as `/bin/sh`, I am able to modify root-owned files and directories:

```
$ rm -rf /opt/foobar/
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/foobar/’: Permission denied
$ ./su /bin/sh
# rm -rf /opt/foobar
# exit
```

However, `/bin/bash` doesn't seem to get root permissions:

```
$ ./su /bin/bash
bash-4.3$ rm -rf /opt/foobar/
rm: cannot remove ‘/opt/foobar/’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Never use ROOT in Bash, use sudo for security reasons.

Comment: Your program doesn't actually do anything. Where do you think it sets the user ID? It has permission to, but it never does.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You missed its binary had root suid bit set afterwards.

Comment: That gives it permission to change its user ID, for example, by calling `setreuid`, but where does the program do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shells reset the euid to the uid for security reasons. So if you really want to have a *rooted* shell, you need to enforce uid **and** euid to 0. Set-uid bit only change the effective user id.

You need to set the user id to 0 for `bash` to be run as root:

```
...
setuid(0);
int ret = execv (argv[0], argv);
...
```

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks for adding the underlying reason!

Comment: Hi. Can I know any reference of this useful answer?

Comment: @happychild  Bash source code ([shell.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/shell.c)): `if (running_setuid && privileged_mode == 0)
    disable_priv_mode ();` → `setuid (current_user.uid)`.